# Transliteration + translation of pangram

Tags: traducción

> La cigüeña tocaba cada vez mejor el saxofón y el búho pedía kiwi y
>   queso.

How do you transliterate this into US ASCII characters? And what does the phrase mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transliteration is simple: barely remove the accents and change "ñ" to "ny".

Translation might sound even more absurd in English than it is in Spanish, as it is just a sentence which lets the reader realize how does a computer font look... but well... it might be "The stork played the saxophone better and better and the owl asked for kiwi and cheese."

Comment: You can also translate the "ñ" to "ng"

Answer (score 0):

Search Google for an ASCII table.

You can type them, in Windows at least, with ALT + CODE 
The only one I know by heart is ALT + 164 = ñ  ALT + 165 = Ñ